# Passing a parenthesized function pointer without knowing the parentclass in compile time

Tags: c++, class, pointers

i am trying to set up a simulation in gazebo using rti connext as communication service to transport some parameters to external software.

For this, i have to initialize the communication by passing a function pointer to the subscriber_init which is called, when new data instances arrived.

subscriber.h

```
void (*callback)(int i);
int subscriber_init(int domainId, char* topicName, callback cbPointer);
```

Calling this by any c file which includes the subcriber.h is no problem. However, if i try to set my communication up inside a class the problems start to rise.

Plugin.cxx

```
#include subscriber.h
class Plugin{
  void load(){
    callback cbPointer = &Plugin::handler;
    subscriber_init(0,"Topic",cbPointer);
  }
  void handler(int i){ 
    //do someting
  }
}
```

Which gives me an error in form of

```
error: cannot convert ‘void (Plugin::*)(int)’ to ‘callback {aka void (*)(int)}’ in initialization callback cpPointer = &Plugin::handler
```

How can i make a typedef without knowing the parent classes of the passed function pointer in advantage?

Disclaimer: Not compiling examples, just to make clear what i am trying to do

Comment: As the error indicates, a method pointer is not compatible with a function pointer.

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements? Are you able to change the way `subscriber_init` is defined? What is the purpose of the `int i` parameter? What does the `i` parameter represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass pointer to object to your *callback* function or use `void*` like that:

```
typedef void (*callback)(int i, void* pParam);
int subscriber_init(int domainId, char* topicName, callback cbPointer, void* pParam)
{
    //...
    cbPointer(someInt, pParam);
    //...
}
```

And update your Plugin class with corresponded *static* `Handler()` function.

```
class Plugin{
  void load(){
    callback cbPointer = &Plugin::handler;
    subscriber_init(0,"Topic", cbPointer, this);
  }

   void handler(int i){
     //do someting
   }

   static void handler(int i, void *pParam){
     Plugin *plg = static_cast<Plugin*>(pParam);
     plg->handler(i);
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`handler()` is a class method. It is not a function.

Either change `handler()` to a static class function:

```
static void handler(int i);
```

Or use some other function. But if your intent is to invoke a class method, then your subscriber_init() needs both a method pointer, and a class instance pointer:

```
int subscriber_init(int domainId, char* topicName,
    void (*Plugin::*callback)(), Plugin *ptr);
```

Then your `subscriber_init`() can invoke a method of the instantiated class:

```
ptr->*callback();
```

Then your `load()` can pass the required parameters:

```
void load(){
    subscriber_init(0,"Topic",&Plugin::handler, this);
}
```

Comment: Because i am pretty new to cpp i have to ask: a static class function is defined outside the class, right?
Because this is what i am trying right now, but it gives me a "variable or field 'handler' declared void" error, which i really dont understand

On the other hand using a class instance pointer in subscriber.h needs a Plugin.h included, right? 
Because of the structure of gazebo it is not that easy to do this :( 
My goal is a class method pointer, without knowing the class type in advantage...

Comment: A static class function is a function declared with the static keyword, inside the class. You cannot have a class method pointer "without knowing the class type". C++ does not work this way. The class has to be, at least, declared, if not completely defined.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is unfortunate and puts up a lot of work ;( Thank you anyway for your patience

Comment: Nobody has ever accused C++ of being easy, and requiring little effort to get things working right.